# Double click Angular directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-directive, angular7

I have the following template in Angular 7:

```
<ul class="posts">
  <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
    <a (click)="delete(post)">Delete Post</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to create a confirm directive to be used as:

```
<a (click)="delete(post)" confirm="Confirm delete" class="delete">Delete Post</a>
```

The moment is clicked (one is enough) it changes to:

```
<a (click)="delete(post)" confirm="Confirm delete" class="delete confirm">Confirm delete</a>
```

So what happens is:
- Anchor's text changes from "Delete Post" to the one inside confirm, e.g. "Confirm Delete";
- Class "confirm" is added to anchor CSS classes;
- Delete(post) method is only called after anchor being clicked on "confirm mode";
- After being clicked on "confirm mode" OR 5 seconds go by without being clicked it goes to its original state:

```
<a (click)="delete(post)" confirm="Confirm delete" class="delete">Delete Post</a>
```

Can this be done with a directive?

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[confirm]'
})

export class ConfirmDirective {

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
     el.nativeElement ...
  }

}
```

I started to create the directive but I am really not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update:

If you really want to, you actually can do it with a directive. Try this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject, timer, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[confirm]'
})
export class ConfirmDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('confirm') delete: Function;
  private confirm$ = fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'click');
  private confirmTimeout: number = 5000;
  private timer$: Observable<number>;
  private isConfirming = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private isConfirming$ = this.isConfirming.asObservable();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isConfirming$.subscribe((isConfirming) => this.setLabel(isConfirming));
    this.confirm$.subscribe((event: any) => this.doConfirm());
  }

  setLabel(isConfirming: boolean): void {
    // set the correct element text and styles
    let text: any;
    let textEl = this.renderer.createElement('span');

    if (this.el.nativeElement.firstChild) {
      this.renderer.removeChild(this.el.nativeElement, this.el.nativeElement.firstChild);
    }
    if (this.isConfirming.value) { // we are confirming right now
      text = this.renderer.createText('Please confirm delete');
      this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'delete');
    } else {
      text = this.renderer.createText('Delete');
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'delete');
    }

    this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, text);
  }

  doConfirm(): void {
    if (this.isConfirming.value === false) { // start confirming
      this.timer$ = timer(this.confirmTimeout);
      this.isConfirming.next(true);

      // start the timer
      this.timer$
          .pipe(
            takeUntil(this.confirm$) // stop timer when confirm$ emits (this happens when the button is clicked again)
          )
            .subscribe(() => {
            this.isConfirming.next(false); // timeout done - confirm cancelled
        });
    } else { // delete confirmation
      this.isConfirming.next(false);
      this.delete(); // this is the delete action that was passed to the directive
    }
  }
}
```

You would apply it to an element like this, passing in the actual `delete` method as a parameter.

```
<button type="button" [confirm]="delete"></button>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wdfcux

### Old answer:

Not sure a directive would be the best way to go. It could probably be done but you'd have to intercept the click handler somehow and/or pass the delete method to it. It would probably be messy.

I'd probably create a component for the delete button and handle it there (well actually that's a lie, if this were me I'd use the native `confirm` dialog and be done with it, but you don't want to).

Something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'delete-button',
  template: `<button type="button" (click)="delete()" [ngClass]="{ delete: isConfirming }">{{ label }}</button>`,
  styles: ['.delete { background-color: teal; color: white; } ']
})
export class DeleteButtonComponent {
  private confirmTimeout: number = 5000;
  private timer$: Observable<number>;
  private cancelTimer = new Subject();
  public isConfirming: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  get label(): string {
    return this.isConfirming
      ? 'Please confirm delete'
      : 'Delete'
  }

  delete() {
    if (!this.isConfirming) {
      this.timer$ = timer(this.confirmTimeout);
      this.isConfirming = true;

      this.timer$
          .pipe(
            takeUntil(this.cancelTimer)
          ).subscribe(() => {
            this.isConfirming = false;
        }, null, () => this.isConfirming = false);
    } else {
      this.cancelTimer.next();
      // really delete
    }
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6fek4

Comment: Thank you for your code. The reason why I would like a directive is that I would be able to use it in a button, anchor, etc. And could also use the native HTML tags as usual. Amazing how a task easy to implement in JQuery is complex in Angular.

Comment: I understand that the confirm dialog could be easier but in this project I will need to set it this way ...

Comment: @MiguelMoura I figured out a way to do it in a directive. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rxjs takeUntil,

```
posts: any[] = [
  { id: 1, title: 'post 1', deleteText: 'Delete Post' },
  { id: 2, title: 'post 2', deleteText: 'Delete Post' }
];

delete(post) {
  post.deleteText = 'Click to Confirm';
  post.css = 'custom';
  let confirm$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('post-' + post.id), 'click');
  let timer$ = timer(5000)

  confirm$
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(timer$)
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
      console.log('ready to delete');
      this.posts = this.posts.filter(p => p.id !== post.id);
    });



  timer$
    .subscribe(() => {
      if (this.posts.find(p => p.id === post.id)) {
        console.log('timer is up, abort delete');
        post.deleteText = 'Delete Post';
        post.css = '';
      }
    });
  }
```

HtML:

```
<ul class="posts">
   <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
      <a (click)="delete(post)" [ngClass]="post.css" [id]="'post-'+post.id">          {{post.deleteText}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-xg8phb

(also need to manage subscriptions)

Comment: But can't this be done using a directive? The reason why I am looking for a directive is to keep this logic outside in the HTML and outside of the component code. And also to reuse it ...Other than that the behaviour of the code you posted is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: you can extract the logic into directive.

Answer (score -1):

You can add host element behavior bindings and listeners through a directive with `@HostBinding` and `@HostListener`, as well as arbitrary `@Input`s bound to the directive itself:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[confirm]'
})

export class ConfirmDirective {

  @HostListener('dblclick') onDoubleClick(event) {
    // .. do double click logic, just like binding (dbclick) to an element
  }

  @HostBinding('class.confirm') confirmStyle: boolean; // toggles class on host, just like with template binding

  @Input('confirm') confirm: boolean; // State from outside the directive that can be bound to the directive attribute directly, i.e. 'click to confirm' box

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
     el.nativeElement ...
  }

}
```

If you're looking to directly add HTML / markup with the directive for a confirm button, this behavior is instead better wrapped with a component instead. Components are for views; directives are for behavior. One idea is to wrap the confirm dialog(?) into a service that the directive can call.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explained myself correctly ... I update by question. I do not want to use a dialog. All I want is to use the anchor ... When it is clicked (once is enough) it goes to a "confirm mode" waiting for a second click. And just then calls the method delete(post). Does this make sense?